# Как из строки получить числа типа Double

Tags: c#

У меня есть Poco объект, который выглядит следующим образом

```
public class Image
{
   public int X {get;set;}
   public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

Также у меня имеется xml строка `width:263.25pt;height:185.25pt`

Как из этой строки получить необходимые мне значения ширины и высоты?

Comment: `var matches = Regex.Matches("width:263.25pt;height:185.25pt", @"(\d){3}").Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Value));`. Но это только чтобы получить числа (без точки будет)

Comment: @Aarnihauta, а если размер будет четырёхзначный? Тут же только для последовательности из 3 цифр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так получится.

```
string text = "width:263.25pt;height:185.25pt";
var values = text.Split(';')
    .Select(x => x.Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => double.Parse(pair[1].Replace("pt", ""), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Image result = new Image { X = values["width"], Y = values["height"] };
```

Только в Image `int` на `double` поменяйте. Не путайте пункты и пиксели.

Comment: а подскажите, пожалуйста, если число представлено следующим образом .75pt как его конвертировать? Я так понимаю это 0.75, но в строке оно отображено как .75

Comment: @ДимаСтепанов для исходной строки `.Replace(":.", ":0.")`